# SQL Server Truncation Error when column length should be sufficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008

Table Name : tbl_device 
Table Structure:

```
Column  | Type
col1    | nvarchar(200)
```

Now when i try to insert data into this (it works for shorter cases but) and the string data is long i.e. with 
LEN function it is 162

Still the server gives error :

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

what should be the reason for it ??

Comment: Please provide repro code because this problem shouldn't exist. Your code has a bug, need to look at it.

Comment: Are you sure it's *this* column that's receiving the message? Also, could then data have trailing blanks? [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."

Comment: Cn you show us what the string looks like?

Comment: Are you inserting via SQL or in the edit table view in Management Studio? My Management Studio throws this all the time but raw SQL inserts are fine.

Comment: Maybe you have a trigger on that table that's using a temp table/table var with a smaller column length?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's the ticket, because this is the most useless exception message ever expressly _because_ it doesn't tell which column is sad.

Comment: @jonnyGold - I agree its unfortunate. But, I can *almost* see a justification for it - if SQL was to stay set based, and report the exact error locations, it ought to report *all* of the errors, for *all* rows - but that could be expensive to compute. So, it's telling you that there's *one* issue in the data, and you ought to examine all of it (other rows could have the exact same issue in a different column)

Comment: One weird thing i found regarding this was when we press alt+F1 or say describe the table it showed me the length of nvarchar as 200 but the culprit was when i went and checked the Table in design view it told me nvarchar(100) !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are trailing blanks in the string that generates the error message but they are not counted using `len()` function.